# Reveal.js iframe background

Tags: html, css, presentation, reveal.js

I want an embedded iframe to be full screen (or an adjusted percentage of the full screen) in a reveal.js presentation.  [This](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/751) discussion implies that I can set the iframe as a background, but this returns the default background:

```
<section data-background="http://viz.healthmetricsandevaluation.org/fgh">
</section>
```

I have also tried putting the iframe in a div with class stretch, but it only takes up a percentage of the screen:

```
<div class = "stretch">
     <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://viz.healthmetricsandevaluation.org/fgh"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question about interacting with the background iframes:

Use the dev branch on reveal.js to get the data-background-iframe feature. Implement this small patch to interact with the iframes until something similar gets merged in.

```js
function showSlide( slide ) {
    // ...

    if( background ) {
        // ...
        document.querySelector('.reveal > .backgrounds').style['z-index'] = 0;
        // ...
        if( background.hasAttribute( 'data-loaded' ) === false ) {
            // ...
            if( backgroundImage ) {
                // ...
            }
            // ...
           else if ( backgroundIframe ) {
               // ...
              document.querySelector('.reveal > .backgrounds').style['z-index'] = 1;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

To be clear, the two lines being added are:

```
document.querySelector('.reveal > .backgrounds').style['z-index'] = 0; // reset when not in iframe
document.querySelector('.reveal > .backgrounds').style['z-index'] = 1; // set when in iframe
```

reference: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/pull/1029#issuecomment-65373274

Answer (score 8):

perhaps you already figured it out, it's seem to be recent improvement:

```
<section data-background-iframe="https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js">
</section>
```

reference:
https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/pull/1029

Comment: Is there a way to interact with the background iframes?

Comment: This is genius. Very nice feature. You can interact with the data-background-iframe like you would have opened the website.. Then go on with your presentation...